# Function working in an unload event but not in a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a logout function which is called in two different events.  One is an unload event, the other is a click event.  If I unload or refresh the page, the function is called and the user is logged out.  However, when I click the logout button, the function isn't called.  Can anyone explain why?

**js**

```
var loc = "../pages/logged_out.php";
    function logout(location){
        $.post("../php/logout.php", {}, function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                location.replace(location);
            }
        }, "json");
    }

    $("#logout").on("click", function(){
        logout(loc);
    })

    $(window).unload(function(){
        logout(loc);
    })
```

**html**

`<button class="button" name="logout" id="logout">Logout</button>`

**Edit:**  One thing I failed to mention is that if I make the function anonymous and don't try to pass the location as an argument, the script works fine.

Comment: **You need to bind event once element is available in DOM**, try wrapping it in document ready handler or set it just before closing BODY tag or delegate event

Comment: It's already in a document.ready function

Comment: Is this element dynamically added to the DOM? Is there any duplicate IDs?

Comment: UM, The Ajax call will be in a race condition on unload, you will be lucky if it actually makes it to the server in modern browsers.

Comment: @A.Wolff no, it's statically added in the HTML file

Comment: @epascarello what exactly is a race condition and why would this work if I didn't pass the location as an argument?

Comment: @Robert You have to provide minimalistic sample which replicates your issue, btw, your unload handler isn't cross browser, your ajax request will be aborded before being completed

Comment: Solution: *Rename either the function or the button and it should start to work.* Why a race condition? When the browser closes or exits to new page, it will abort Ajax/http calls from going out. Just have to cross your fingers it makes it to the server. That is why the server has session end events.

Comment: And check your console for any error, maybe a context issue

Comment: @epascarello the session is closed in the logout.php file.  That's not the issue.  As I said, If I don't pass the location as an argument, the script works the way it should.

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm not getting any errors

Comment: I am not saying that the unload is the issue, when you get it out into the real world servers, you will be wondering why all of these sessions are never closed. Did you rename the button or function yet?

Comment: I renamed the function, still didn't work.

Comment: @epascarello how do I fix the AJAX issue you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you defined a variable location and try to use location.replace

```
function logout(location){   <-- variable location
    $.post("../php/logout.php", {}, function (response){
        if(response.success == "1"){
            location.replace(location);   <-- trying to use replace on itself
        }
    }, "json");
}
```

rename `location` to a different variable. The browser has no clue you actually mean `window.location.replace()`

```
function logout (redirectLocation) {   
    $.post("../php/logout.php", {}, function(response){
        if(response.success == "1"){
            window.location.replace(redirectLocation);   
        }
    }, "json");
}
```

Comment: This will fix the AJAX and cross browser issues you mentioned?

Comment: It is not going to fix the race condition of unload...there is not much you can do there.